# XML Deserialization {"Root element is missing."} Error

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm adding a new project to my Solution, and have added the code posted below. The LoadXML() method, variable setup, and file deserialization is done exactly as I have done it several other times throughout this Solution, but suddenly now for this part it is throwing this annoying "{"Root element is missing."}" error - even when there is no XML present or when I use a different XML I know works. This means to me that the bug is obviously in the code, but since the code is almost carbon-copied from my previous file transfers, I don't know how that could be either. The other situations for this error previously posted on this website do not really conform to my situation, so I started a fresh one in hopes I might land closer to an answer!

```
    //fileName and XML variables for serialization/deserialization
    const string fileName = "SimulatedTrain1.xml";
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BindingList<SimulatedTrain>));

    //Create BindingList object to hold XML data
    public BindingList<SimulatedTrain> SimulatedTrain = new BindingList<SimulatedTrain>();

    public void LoadXML()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                var tempTrain = (BindingList<SimulatedTrain>)xml.Deserialize(fs);
                SimulatedTrain = tempTrain;
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

The LoadXML() gets called on the form_load

Edit: Here's a part of my XML file (the rest is basically repeat data)

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your `SimulatedTrain1.xml` ?

Comment: Threw it up there for you to see!

Comment: possibly try `FileMode.Open` instead of `OpenOrCreate`?

Comment: also make sure that it is finding that file instead of creating one

Comment: @terbubbs I have tried setting the FileMode to every option available, and it still sends out the same error. The problem seems to be not with the XML or FileMode, but something in between the cracks so to speak. The error itself happens at the end of the Using() statement, as soon as my program tries to execute the FileMode operation

Comment: tried setting `fs.Position = 0`? just brainstorming everything i can possibly think of

Comment: Doesn't seem to have an effect, however, I did notice something potentially interesting:

If I breakpoint to the Using() statement, it throws an error at the end of the Using line; however, if I just run the program without breakpoints, the error shows up on the "var tempTrain = ..." line instead

Same error both times, just appears to happen in the two spots depending on if a breakpoint is present

I thought I might try hard coding the file path from C: instead of just letting the compiler assume it's local to the Solution

Comment: Look this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms172873(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There's likely a problem with your classes annotations - the serializer is expecting a different root node name or namespace.

Comment: It seemed to be a two-headed issue: first, the tags in my XML were set to the wrong instance of my trains (got the names backwards between SimulatedTrain and RailCar) and second, the XmlSerializer didn't like when I gave it just the local file path. Instead, I had to plug in the entire path starting with C:\\      It all seems to be working the data correctly now!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the XML file is copied into your build directory by selecting ["Copy to Output Directory" to be "Copy always"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCcha.png).

Assuming that the file exists, you probably have a type conversion error in deserializing the XML file.

The following works:

SimulatedTrain.cs:

```
[XmlRoot("ArrayOfSimulatedRailCar")]
public class SimulatedTrain
{
    [XmlElement("SimulatedRailCar")]
    public List<SimulatedRailCar> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

SimulatedRailCar.cs:

```
public class SimulatedRailCar
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    // More properties here...
}
```

TrainProg.cs:

```
const string fileName = "SimulatedTrain1.xml";
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SimulatedTrain));

public SimulatedTrain SimulatedTrain;

public void LoadXML()
{
    Contract.Assert(File.Exists(fileName));

    try
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            SimulatedTrain = (SimulatedTrain)xml.Deserialize(fs);
        }                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was an interesting approach to try out. After mimicking this setup, I did notice a change; however, I cannot say whether or not it was necessarily for the better:    I now receive a message saying there is an error at (2,2) instead of (0,0), and says " '<ArrayOfSimulatedRailCar xmlns=' was not expected "

Comment: As in my code, you should set XmlRoot to ArrayOfSimulatedRailCar. Additionally, remove the `xmlns` stuff in your xml file so that it reads `< ArrayOfSimulatedRailCar>`.